# python least significant 6 bits of integer

Tags: python, bit-shift

I'm trying to find the least significant 6 bits of a 16 bit integer. Let's say my integer is 139 / 0x008B.

```
>>> "{0:b}".format(139)
'10001011'
```

So the least significant 6 bits are:

```
'001011'
>>> int('001011', 2)
11
```

However, I thought I could do this with the >> operator, but that isn't giving me what I expect:

```
>>> 139 >> 6
2
```

Can someone explain the difference between these two?

Comment: Can't post a full answer because on mobile, but you have to use a bitmask: `number & 0x3f`. `0x3f` is literally `0b111111`, and `&` is a bitwise `and`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shifts are for re-positioning bits, not for isolating them. This is called "masking", and in your case you need a bitmask that you "and" with your number. This is done with the &-operator in Python. It's fundamentally different from the logical "and"-operator, so don't confuse them!

```
>>> bin(139 & 0b111111)
'0b1011'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use the bit-wise 'and' operator (`&`) and not the right-shift operator (`>>`).

Try the following: `139 & 0b111111`

That should give you the 6 least-significant bits.